# How to access from an interface the value of a specific key and use it as a type for a mapped value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Error**: *Argument of type '(currency: CurrenciesResponse, index: number) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { iso_code: string; name: string; }, index: number, array: { iso_code: string; name: string; }[]) => Element'.
Types of parameters 'currency' and 'value' are incompatible.
Property 'data' is missing in type '{ iso_code: string; name: string; }' but required in type 'CurrenciesResponse'.*

I have this code:

```
 {data &&
              data.data.map((currency: CurrenciesResponse, index: number) => (
                <div
                  className="w-fit max-w-full cursor-pointer overflow-hidden truncate rounded-lg px-2 py-1 text-right text-sm font-normal hover:bg-inpay-green-700 hover:text-white"
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {
                    setCurrency(currency.iso_code);
                    onCurrencyChange(currency.iso_code);
                  }}
                >
                  {currency.name}
                </div>
              ))}
```

The **currenciesResponse** is the type where the error lies. Which looks like this:

```
export interface CurrenciesResponse {
  data: Array<{
    iso_code: string;
    name: string;
  }>;
}
```

Going back to my component instead of using **CurrenciesResponse** as the type I need to get from the CurrenciesResponse the array inside the data key, inside the CurrenciesResponse. If I am correct. So the question is. How do I access from the interface CurrenciesResponse the value of the data key or if I am wrong the value I need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your anonymous function and the variable you're passing to it. `data.data.map((currency: CurrenciesResponse, index: number) => (`

If the type of `currency` is `CurrenciesResponse`, then currency will be something like this

```
// which means currency.iso_code doesn't exist
// rather, you will have something like this currency.data[0].iso_code
const currency = {
  data: [
    {
      iso_code: "GB",
      name: "Pounds",
    },
    {
      iso_code: "US",
      name: "Dollars",
    },
  ],
};
```

I think your code should be more like this

```
function CurrencyFn({ data }: { data: CurrenciesResponse }) {
  const setCurrency = (iso_code: string) => {
    // write code here
  };
  const onCurrencyChange = (iso_code: string) => {
    // write code here
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {data && data.data.map(
        (
          currency /** Type is automatically inferred */,
          index /** index is number by default */
        ) => (
          <div
            className="w-fit max-w-full cursor-pointer overflow-hidden truncate rounded-lg px-2 py-1 text-right text-sm font-normal hover:bg-inpay-green-700 hover:text-white"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
              setCurrency(currency.iso_code);
              onCurrencyChange(currency.iso_code);
            }}
          >
            {currency.name}
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or if you are using react hook, something like this

```
const [data, setData] = useState<CurrenciesResponse | null>(null);
useEffect(() => {
  fetchCurrencies().then(setData);
}, []);
```

if you want to state the type of currency, it should be

```
interface Currency {
  iso_code: string;
  name: string;
}

data.data.map((currency: Currency, index: number)
```

Hope this helps.